# Installing spyder python on windows 8

Tags: python, pyqt, pip, pyside, spyder

I would like to install spyder (the math IDE for python, here 2.7) on my windows 8.1 machine.

1. I did install python starting from http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/;
2. I did install pip after having installed setuptools, following http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html for these installations;
3. I did change my path to add C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts to it, digging into the advanced parameters of my PC's properties. (By the way, I can't beleive the way you do this on windows has not changed for ages, with such a small input where you forgot to go at the end of the value when adding your path...)
4. I did install spyder

   ```
   pip install spyder
   ```

But when launching it in command line (it's in the path :-) ), I ran through this error:

```
RuntimeError: Please check Spyder installation requirements:
PyQt4 4.4+ (or PySide 1.1.1+) is required.
```

Which is truly true. Though,

- when trying to pip PyQt4 :

  ```
  No distributions at all found for PyQt4
  ```
- when trying to pip PySide, I have many errors, the root one seeming that it is unable to find nmake

Any piece of advice ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install PySide on Windows you can choose from the following options:

1. Download and install the packages from the [releases page](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Windows).
2. Use setuptools to install the egg binary packages:

   c:> c:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install PySide
3. Use pip to install the wheel binary packages:

   c:> c:\Python27\Scripts\pip install --use-wheel PySide

Details are here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#installing-pyside-on-a-windows-system

BTW: PyQt does not support setuptools or pip

Comment: I used the third option and it worked perfectly. I am currently learning the goal of the use-wheel option. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have installed Python2.7 64 bit after uninstalling the related files of Python2.7 32 bit then i faced similar problem. I did the first option and it worked but launching Spyder just opens command window for 1 or 2 second and then disappers and nothing happens next. Do you have any idea about this

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if its a proper answer, but you might want to take a look at [PythonXY](http://python-xy.github.io/). It makes all these installation procedure a breeze.

Comment: Having found Python-xy through this answer, I should say that it made installation fast, quick and easy!

Answer (score 0):

From the details in your question, it looks like you are missing both PyQt4 and Qt itself.

There are binary installers for Windows available from the [PyQt download page](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download). These installers include both PyQt *and* Qt (as well as various other tools such as Qt Designer). The only things *not* included are the Qt documentation, and Python itself (which you seem to have already installed).

Just be careful to select the right installer from the list of **Binary Packages**: i.e. the one for **Python-2.7**, plus whatever architecture is appropriate for your system.